# Insert Row without Pasting

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to debug the following small macro:

```
Sub InsertRowAbove()
'
' InsertRow Macro
' Pushes active row down
'
    Dim N As Long
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("G4").Copy Range("G5:G" & N)
    Range("J4").Copy Range("J5:J" & N)

End Sub
```

The macro should allow the user to insert an empty row directly above the active cell and fill down formulas in columns **G** and **J**.

The macro works.

If, however, the user performs a copy/paste operation just before  running the macro, the macro will attempt to also paste material into the new row.

We want to macro to leave the newly inserted row empty.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Clear the clipboard before the Insert (might be a little annoying for your user) or clear the inserted rows after the Insert ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Clearing the clipboard fixes the problem..... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line to disable `CutCopyMode`:

```
Sub InsertRowAbove()
'
' InsertRow Macro
' Pushes active row down
'
    Dim N As Long

    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'This line to get rid of clipboard.

    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("G4").Copy Range("G5:G" & N)
    Range("J4").Copy Range("J5:J" & N)

End Sub
```